# 2 column website using inline box + width

Tags: html, css

I'm new to using HTML and CSS. I'm having some trouble moving the "BOUGHT HIS FIRST STOCK AT 14 YEARS OLD" column beside the "ORACLE FROM OMAHA", using

```
display: inline-block
Width:X%
```

Can anyone help me explain what I'm doing wrong?

```css
/* FONTS 
font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
*/


/* column texten */

body {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  background-color: #f9f7f1;
}

header {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 72px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* boxarna på sidan */

.div-content1 {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  word-spacing: -.31em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 2% 0 2%;
}

.div-colummen1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.div-colummen1 .Rubrik-1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.div-colummen1 .Rubrik-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.div-colummen1 .Rubrik-3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.div-colummen1 .Rubrik-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neuton:200|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div1.1">
    <header>Warren Buffet</header>
  </div>

  <div class="div-content1">
    <div class="div-columer1">

      <div class="div-colummen1">
        <div class="div1"><span class="Rubrik-1">The Oracle From Omaha</span>
          <p><span class="Rubrik-2">business magnate, investor, and philanthropist</span>

            <p>
              <div>
                Nullam a lectus nec nulla congue pellentesque. Proin lacinia dictum nisi ut hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam ex tellus, tincidunt sed nulla in, rutrum pharetra nisl. Nam tincidunt
                arcu ut venenatis dignissim. Praesent rhoncus accumsan lectus non ultrices. Vivamus laoreet, turpis in consectetur dictum, ante magna aliquam metus, vel ultrices metus turpis eu massa. Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis
                suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>
            </div>

            <p>
              <div>
                Nullam a lectus nec nulla congue pellentesque. Proin lacinia dictum nisi ut hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam ex tellus, tincidunt sed nulla in, rutrum pharetra nisl. Nam tincidunt
                arcu ut venenatis dignissim. Praesent rhoncus accumsan lectus non ultrices. Vivamus laoreet, turpis in consectetur dictum, ante magna aliquam metus, vel ultrices metus turpis eu massa. Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis
                suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>
            </div>


            <div class="div1"><span class="Rubrik-3">Grew up in a poor family</span>
              <p><span class="Rubrik-4">quis congue enim maximus</span></p>
            </div>

            <p>
              Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>

            <p>
              Nam tincidunt arcu ut venenatis dignissim. Praesent rhoncus accumsan lectus non ultrices. Vivamus laoreet, turpis in consectetur dictum, ante magna aliquam metus, vel ultrices metus turpis eu massa. Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis
              suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>


            <div class="div-colummen1">
              <div class="div1"><span class="Rubrik-3">Bought his first stock at 14 years old</span>
                <p><span class="Rubrik-4">quis congue enim maximus</span></p>
              </div>

              <p>
                Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>

              <p>
                Nam tincidunt arcu ut venenatis dignissim. Praesent rhoncus accumsan lectus non ultrices. Vivamus laoreet, turpis in consectetur dictum, ante magna aliquam metus, vel ultrices metus turpis eu massa. Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis
                suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>
```

[Codepen Link Here](https://codepen.io/Robbanet/pen/jGVRKr)

Comment: I also added style to div `.div-colummen1` i.e `box-sizing:border-box` forgot to mention earlier. :-) Please check the update code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated answer, only few enclosing tags were not right. I also added style to div `.div-colummen1` i.e `box-sizing:border-box`. Hope it is helpful to you.

```css
/* FONTS 
font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
*/


/* column texten */

body {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  background-color: #f9f7f1;
}

header {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 72px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* boxarna på sidan */

.div-content1 {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  word-spacing: -.31em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 2% 0 2%;
}

.div-colummen1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div-colummen1 .Rubrik-1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.div-colummen1 .Rubrik-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.div-colummen1 .Rubrik-3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.div-colummen1 .Rubrik-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neuton:200|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div1.1">
    <header>Warren Buffet</header>
  </div>

  <div class="div-content1">
    <div class="div-columer1">

      <div class="div-colummen1">
        <div class="div1"><span class="Rubrik-1">The Oracle From Omaha</span>
          <p><span class="Rubrik-2">business magnate, investor, and philanthropist</span></p>
</div>
            
              <div>
              <p>
                Nullam a lectus nec nulla congue pellentesque. Proin lacinia dictum nisi ut hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam ex tellus, tincidunt sed nulla in, rutrum pharetra nisl. Nam tincidunt
                arcu ut venenatis dignissim. Praesent rhoncus accumsan lectus non ultrices. Vivamus laoreet, turpis in consectetur dictum, ante magna aliquam metus, vel ultrices metus turpis eu massa. Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis
                suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>
            </div>

            
              <div>
              <p>
                Nullam a lectus nec nulla congue pellentesque. Proin lacinia dictum nisi ut hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam ex tellus, tincidunt sed nulla in, rutrum pharetra nisl. Nam tincidunt
                arcu ut venenatis dignissim. Praesent rhoncus accumsan lectus non ultrices. Vivamus laoreet, turpis in consectetur dictum, ante magna aliquam metus, vel ultrices metus turpis eu massa. Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis
                suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="div-colummen1">
            <div class="div1"><span class="Rubrik-3">Grew up in a poor family</span>
              <p><span class="Rubrik-4">quis congue enim maximus</span></p>
            </div>

            <p>
              Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>

            <p>
              Nam tincidunt arcu ut venenatis dignissim. Praesent rhoncus accumsan lectus non ultrices. Vivamus laoreet, turpis in consectetur dictum, ante magna aliquam metus, vel ultrices metus turpis eu massa. Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis
              suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>
</div>

            <div class="div-colummen1">
              <div class="div1"><span class="Rubrik-3">Bought his first stock at 14 years old</span>
                <p><span class="Rubrik-4">quis congue enim maximus</span></p>
              </div>

              <p>
                Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>

              <p>
                Nam tincidunt arcu ut venenatis dignissim. Praesent rhoncus accumsan lectus non ultrices. Vivamus laoreet, turpis in consectetur dictum, ante magna aliquam metus, vel ultrices metus turpis eu massa. Nunc vel libero sed elit dapibus eleifend. Proin mollis
                suscipit metus non accumsan. Nunc maximus massa sit amet mattis tincidunt. Nunc ac pulvinar est, sit amet laoreet mi. Proin posuere libero sagittis tortor pretium, quis congue enim maximus.</p>
                
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not in your css, it's in your html : only the third column has the attribute ".div-colummen1".

you need to put all your tree columns in three ".div-colummen1" divs

(set width to 30%)

```
.div-colummen1{
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
vertical-align: top;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

And the html

```
<div class="div-colummen1">
  <div class="div1"><span class="Rubrik-1">The Oracle From Omaha</span></div>
</div>
<div class="div-colummen1">
  <div class="div1"><span class="Rubrik-3">Grew up in a poor family</span></div>
</div>
<div class="div-colummen1">
  <div class="div1"><span class="Rubrik-3">Bought his first stock at 14 years old</span></div>
</div>
```

but wait, why cant i set 33% as 33*3 = 99% ?
Because of the padding and borders.,You can avoid that by adding box-sizing border-box to your column

```
.div-colummen1{
box-sizing:border-box;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 33.33%;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
vertical-align: top;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Okey, thank you everyone, seems like its working as i want now :)

Comment: @Robbert perfect :D don't forget to accept one of our answers ;)